# How do I control the Hadoop task retry policy using command line options?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'd like to control the Hadoop job retry policy using command line options. For example, I'd like to write the following Sqoop job and have it be fault tolerant to MySQL outages:

```
sqoop
  GENERIC_SQOOP_OPTIONS
  -Dmap.retry.exponentialBackOff=TRUE
  -Dmap.retry.numRetries=10
```

For a general Hadoop job, it might look something like:

```
hadoop job -submit
  GENERIC_JOB_OPTIONS
  -Dmap.retry.exponentialBackOff=TRUE
  -Dmap.retry.numRetries=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hadoop "-D" arguments are supported in Sqoop. However their position on command line is crucial. They must be present directly after "sqoop" and before any other Sqoop arguments:

```
sqoop -Dmap.retry.exponentialBackOff=TRUE -Dmap.retry.numRetries=10 import --connect ...
```

Please note that different positioning will not work as expected.

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work for me... sqoop 1.46.